# iOS: UITableViewController -- cellForRowAtIndexPath cell creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know the Apple docs do not specify that cellForRowAtIndexPath goes in order i.e. First it'll go to Section 0, Index 0; Then Section 0, Index 2; And then  Section 1, Index 0....so on.  I think it jumps around.

What's a better a way to a accomplish below?  Currently I keep getting an error

```
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

The error appears b/c I think cellForRowAtIndexPath jumps around and marks 
`*sectioned = NULL`, so the condition is skipped and it goes to an empty array or exceeds index count by going to a wrong condition.

Here is the code:

```
... declared and synthesized 
NSManaged *object;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *sevenDaysSectionFilled;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *fourteenDaysSectionFilled;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *thirtyDaysSectionFilled;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    object = NULL;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if ((SevenDaysArraySectioned == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) && (sevenDaysSectionFilled != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
        {
            object = [pastSevenDayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            sevenDaysSectionFilled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }

        else if ((fourteenDaysArraySectioned == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) && (fourteenDaysSectionFilled != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
        {
            object = [pastFourteenDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            fourteenDaysSectionFilled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }

        else if ((thirtyDaysArraySectioned == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) && (thirtyDaysSectionFilled != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
        {
            object = [pastThirtyDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            thirtyDaysSectionFilled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if ((fourteenDaysArraySectioned == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) && (fourteenDaysSectionFilled != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
        {
            object = [pastFourteenDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            fourteenDaysSectionFilled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }

        else if ((thirtyDaysArraySectioned == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) && (thirtyDaysSectionFilled != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
        {
            object = [pastThirtyDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            thirtyDaysSectionFilled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }

    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        if ((thirtyDaysArraySectioned == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) && (thirtyDaysSectionFilled != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
        {
             object = [pastThirtyDaysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            thirtyDaysSectionFilled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }
     }

NSString *entityName = [[object entity]name];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %i", entityName, [indexPath row]];

  object = NULL;
  return cell;
}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to accomplish this.  Thanks.

***Edit**

This is a bit complicated but here it is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    numberOfSections = 0;

    if ([pastSevenDayArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastFourteenDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;
    if ([pastArray count] > 0) numberOfSections++;

    [self numberOfCells];


    return numberOfSections;
}
```

numberOfCells

```
-(void)numberOfCells
{
    for (int section = 0; section<numberOfSections; section ++)
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            if ([pastSevenDayArray count] > 0)
            {
                SevenDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastSevenDayArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = sevenDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastFourteenDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                fourteenDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastFourteenDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = fourteenDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                thirtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastThirtyDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = thirtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;

            }
            else if ([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0)
            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if ([pastArray count] > 0)
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionZeroCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionZeroHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }

        else if (section == 1)
        {    
            if (([pastFourteenDaysArray count] > 0) && (fourteenDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                fourteenDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastFourteenDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = fourteenDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (thirtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                thirtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastThirtyDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = thirtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (sixtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionOneCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionOneHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }
        else if (section ==2)
        {
            if (([pastThirtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (thirtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                thirtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastThirtyDaysArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = thirtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (sixtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))

            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionTwoCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionTwoHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }
        else if (section ==3)

        {
            NSLog(@"Entered Section %i", section);

            if (([pastSixtyDaysArray count] > 0) && (sixtyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))            {
                sixtyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionThreeCellCount = [pastSixtyDaysArray count];
                sectionThreeHeader = sixtyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionThreeCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionThreeHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;          
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionThreeCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionThreeHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }
        else if (section ==4)
        {
            NSLog(@"Entered Section %i", section);

            if (([pastNinteyDaysArray count] > 0) && (ninetyDaysArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                ninetyDaysArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionFourCellCount = [pastNinteyDaysArray count];
                sectionFourHeader = ninetyDaysSectionLabel;
            }
            else if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionFourCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionFourHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }

        else if (section ==5)
        {
            NSLog(@"Entered Section %i", section);

            if (([pastArray count] > 0) && (pastArraySectioned != [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]))
            {
                pastArraySectioned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                sectionFiveCellCount = [pastArray count];
                sectionFiveHeader = pastSectionLabel;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

numberOfRowsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0)
    {
        return sectionZeroCellCount;
    }

    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return sectionOneCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 2)
    {
        return sectionTwoCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 3)
    {
        return sectionThreeCellCount;
    }
    else if (section == 4)
    {
        return sectionFourCellCount;
    }
    if (section == 5)
    {
        return sectionFiveCellCount;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Header:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 150)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 10, 25)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if (section == 0)
    {
        label.text = sectionZeroHeader;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        label.text = sectionOneHeader;
    }

    else if (section == 2)
    {
        label.text = sectionTwoHeader;
    }
    else if (section == 3)
    {
        label.text = sectionThreeHeader;
    }
    else if (section == 4)
    {
        label.text = sectionFourHeader;
    }
    else if (section == 5)
    {
        label.text = sectionFiveHeader;
    }    

    [headerView addSubview:label];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: I think your logic to return the number of rows for each section might be incorrect, Looks like its trying to populate four rows in one of your tableviews sections with an array that only contains three elements

Comment: I have verified it so many times.  numberOfRowsInSection: is correct if it matches up with with correct cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Why are you doing the ...sectioned=NULL?

Comment: In some cases, I may not have pastSevenSectionedArray and in Secion 0, it may go to pastFourteenDaysArray.  So I mark             fourteenDaysArraySectioned = NULL; so that in Section 1, it knows that fourteenDaysArray has been displayed in Section 0 and moves on to pastThirthyDaysArray.

Comment: Are those instance variables though? I don't see a declaration in the method for them.

Comment: They are declared under @interface class () in .m and synthesized. I didn't show them in code to save space.

Comment: Got it thanks. Would you mind sharing your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` implementations as well?

Comment: I just updated it with an Edit.  Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: I also did an update on the original code with more clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems like cellForRowAtIndexPath keeps looping at indexPath.Section==1 and when it hits an Array that exceeds its index, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole lot of state being maintained in various instance variables that doesn't have to be. We can use collections and other data structures to build a definition for how the table is supposed to be, and then refer to that in our data source / delegate methods.

The basic idea of this view controller is that each section is represented by a `CVSectionModel` object that contains the row data for that section, and section-specific information such as header views. Inside `viewDidLoad` we build these section models, and any time we finish updating our data we should re-build them. To try that different arrangements of data work, replace the call in `viewDidLoad` to `testCase1` with one of the other test methods.

We maintain an array of section models and only create a model for a section if there's content to show there. As you can see this simplifies the calculation of what array to get row information out of and how many rows go in each section. We simply ask the section model for a section what to do, rather than synchronize several different instance variables.

Note this table controller doesn't support more elaborate animations of content insertion, deletion, or reordering, so additional work would be needed if that's a requirement. It does support regular table re-loading after an update, though, as can be seen in the block that runs 10 seconds after viewDidLoad.

Please examine the code and ask any questions. This is the implementation file, but nothing was in the header except for `@interface CVViewController: UIViewController @end`.

```
@interface CVSectionModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *rowModels;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *sectionTitle;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tag; // possibly useful for animations, different behavior on section, etc.

@end

@implementation CVSectionModel

@end


@interface CVViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *sectionModels;

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *sevenDays;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *fourteenDays;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *thirtyDays;

@end

@implementation CVViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // In your application, you'll be loading and processing your real data
    // But here I'm just going to simulate a number of cases with strings for illustration
    // Call the other methods to try different configurations
    [self testCase1];

    // We call this once on viewDidLoad. You'll also want to call it whenever you update the underlying data, as in the block below
    [self processSectionData];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];

    // Demonstrate support for modifying the underlying data and refresh the view.
    // Uncomment to test it.
//    double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
//    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
//    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
//        [self testCase2];
//        [self processSectionData];
//        [self.tableView reloadData];
//    });
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.sectionModels count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [((CVSectionModel *)self.sectionModels[section]).rowModels count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
    // In your app this appears to be an NSManagedObject of some type, here it's just a string
    NSString *modelForRow = ((CVSectionModel *)self.sectionModels[indexPath.section]).rowModels[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = modelForRow;
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionTitle = ((CVSectionModel *)self.sectionModels[section]).sectionTitle;
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 150)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 10, 25)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = sectionTitle;
    [headerView addSubview:label];
    return headerView;
}

- (void)processSectionData
{
    NSArray *allDayArrays = @[self.sevenDays, self.fourteenDays, self.thirtyDays];
    // You won't use hard-coded strings here - use your sevenDaysSectionLabel, etc. variables instead
    NSArray *labelTitles = @[@"7 days", @"14 days", @"30 days"];
    NSMutableArray *mutableSectionModels = [NSMutableArray array];

    [allDayArrays enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([array count] > 0) {
            CVSectionModel *sectionModel = [[CVSectionModel alloc] init];
            sectionModel.rowModels = array;
            sectionModel.sectionTitle = labelTitles[index];
            sectionModel.tag = index+1; // track this to enable re-ordering in the future
            [mutableSectionModels addObject:sectionModel];
        }
    }];

    // If Animating insertions / deletions will require something more elaborate
    self.sectionModels = [mutableSectionModels copy];
}

// Case 1:
// All three populated
- (void)testCase1
{
    self.sevenDays = @[@"sevendayitem1", @"sevendayitem2", @"sevendayitem3", @"sevendayitem4"];
    self.fourteenDays = @[@"14day item 1", @"14 day item 2"];
    self.thirtyDays = @[@"30 day item 1", @"30 day item 2", @"30 day item 3"];
}

// Case 2:
// self.fourteenDays is empty
- (void)testCase2
{
    self.sevenDays = @[@"sevendayitem1", @"sevendayitem2", @"sevendayitem3", @"sevendayitem4"];
    self.fourteenDays = @[];
    self.thirtyDays = @[@"30 day item 1", @"30 day item 2", @"30 day item 3"];
}

// Case 3:
// self.thirtydays is the only one
- (void)testCase3
{
    self.sevenDays = @[];
    self.fourteenDays = @[];
    self.thirtyDays = @[@"30 day item 1", @"30 day item 2", @"30 day item 3"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.  I will review this in the AM and get back to you.  Looking over it briefly, for simplificaiton, I only displayed three arrays: SevenDays, FourteenDays, ThirtyDays, SixtyDays, NinetyDays, and PastDaysArray.  

My question is do I need to come with a case for each scenario?  Wouldn't it be a bit cumbersome to try to think of every possible testCase?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1107173 You're welcome. No, you do not need to come up any with test cases - they are purely in my code for illustration that it works! It is because I don't have any real data and I wanted to demonstrate this example. Don't worry about the test cases. You will be updating your sevenDays, fourteenDays, etc as normal, and then create `allDayArrays` with each one, does that make sense? So you'll have something like `allDayArrays = @[sevenDays, fourteenDays, 30Days, 60Days, 90Days, past];` in the `processSectionData` method. Is that clear?

Comment: Can we chat when you have a sec?

Comment: WOW!  So much less code and I think it's working.  Have two questions: 1. I'm getting an error at the following line:    cell.textLabel.text = modelForRow;  Error:  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Entity isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: 2nd.  Why cast?  [((CVSectionModel *)self.sectionModels[section]).rowModels count];

Comment: @user1107173 Regarding the exception, my row arrays contain `NSString` objects so I could assign them directly to the label's `text` property . Since your arrays contain `NSManagedObject`s of some sort you'll need to build a string representation from their attributes that makes sense to your requirements. Good question, I didn't really elaborate on that point. Re: the cast, it's just to let me use dot syntax the way I did. You can try without the cast, I'm pretty sure I got a compiler error when I didn't do it though.

Comment: You are gentleman and a scholar!  If you were in SF Bay, I'd buy you dinner.  You have saved me to so much time with this simplicity!  

Thank you so very much!

Comment: Sorry.  Perhaps I spoke to soon.  While cells are being displayed correctly, Header labels are not appearing.  NSLog displays them correctly.  BTW, how does it know if the arrays (sevenDays, fourteenDays....) are empty and skips them and perfectly displays the Header?

Comment: I did an Edit 2 that shows how I was displaying the labels before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35551/discussion-between-carl-veazey-and-user1107173)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be sure that you set appropriate

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

If you want to have multi sections and in each of sections many rows please use NSDictionary and set key --> array value, then

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"section1": @[@"obj1", @"obj2"],@"section2": @[@"obj3", @"obj4"]};
NSInteger numberOfSections = [[dict allKeys] count];// return in numberOfSections
NSArray *values = [dict valueForKey:@"obj1"];// get appropriate array
```