# iOS: UITableView cell.tag number keeps increasing when in and out of the View

Tags: ios, tags, uitableview, cell

How can I keep track if the Cell was assigned a tag number?  I'll have anywhere from 10 - 90 cells created.  However, when I scroll up and down (in and out-of-view), after cells are recreated, the cell Tag number continue to increase.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = rowModels[indexPath.row];
    NSString  *entityName= [[managedObject entity]name];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %i", entityName, [indexPath row]];


    cell.tag = cellTagIndex++;
    NSString *tagString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cell.tag];

    //cellToObjectMap is NSMutableDictionary

    if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"Test1" ])
    {
        [cellToObjectMap setValue:[managedObject valueForKey:@"test1_id"] forKey:tagString];
    }
    else if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"Test2t" ])
    {
        [cellToObjectMap setValue:[managedObject valueForKey:@"test2_id"] forKey:tagString];
    }

    NSLog(@"Cell.tag %@    Value:  %@", tagString, [cellToObjectMap objectForKey:tagString]);

    return cell;

}
```

Log:

```
2013-08-15 19:07:57.243 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 0    Value:  95AB73F8-E0C2-4D17-B6BE-9FC2E696959D
2013-08-15 19:07:57.244 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 1    Value:  EA163C15-0CF1-4275-B939-0ED9F62C240D
2013-08-15 19:07:57.245 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 2    Value:  DDFD36F6-4CAD-4C26-A38C-B22D827199BD
2013-08-15 19:07:57.245 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 3    Value:  AC9FD255-08CF-44C4-B168-E6441D08AC54
2013-08-15 19:07:57.246 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 4    Value:  48C2DE0C-88C3-48CC-BBB1-350088EE9862
2013-08-15 19:07:57.247 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 5    Value:  5C4495A1-FF3D-439E-BD01-88312EF881AD

........  
........ // Cell.tag continues to increase as I scroll up and down the screen.   

2013-08-15 19:10:38.903 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 254    Value:  81CAA228-51F4-464C-8B2B-12D2A66C3BA8
2013-08-15 19:10:38.969 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 255    Value:  7DC03657-B987-4994-8066-5393F77D891B
2013-08-15 19:10:39.052 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 256    Value:  BB1BCFD2-FBD9-46FA-B662-56085254FD46
2013-08-15 19:10:39.169 Time[8510:c07] Cell.tag 257    Value:  0C78EBE0-AD83-4A21-8546-37EA17EAB5CA
```

How can I keep track if a cell number was already assigned a cell.tag, and if it has, how can I be sure if the dictionary has the existing key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to associate objects in your model with cells, don't make the association between the cell directly because cells are reused constantly. Instead, associate it with the index path.

Assuming `cellToObjectMap` is an `NSMutableDictionary`, then try:

```
[cellToObjectMap setObject:[managedObject valueForKey:@"test1_id"] forKey:indexPath];
```

In general, though, you should just use the `indexPath` to access the object directly out of the data structures you have built to represent your table.

Comment: Carl to the rescue again!  Works, but the value assgined by the IndexPath looks like:  2013-08-15 19:48:45.735 Time[8711:c07] IndexPath Assigned Value: <NSIndexPath 0xbc6c2a0> 2 indexes [0, 31]   

Is it okay to assign that value to a Key?  

Also, I'm getting Incompatible pointer types sending NSIndexPath*_ strong to parameter of type 'NSString *' warning

Comment: :) Is `cellToObjectMap` a mutable dictionary? Or is it something else? If it is, are you using `setObject:forKey:` or `setValue:forKey:`?

Comment: It is a mutableDictionry. I was using setValue, then changed it to setObject. After a new section, the indexPath resets to 0.  

 I'm going by your advice on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243612/ios-uitableviewcontroller-cellforrowatindexpath-cell-creation?noredirect=1#comment26750982_18243612.  How do you suggest I keep track of each cell and map it to the objectID.  I need track for didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and pass that object to the next UITableViewController to display the remainder of the keys/values.  Thanks.

Comment: If you just need to get the object associated with an index path, then use the section model again, like `CVSectionModel *sectionModel = self.sectionModels[indexPath.section]; NSManagedObject *object = sectionModel.rowModels[indexPath.row];`. Also looking at your code, are you maintaining some separate `rowModels` array? You should be keeping track of sections only, because the rowModels will vary based on what section you're in, and you don't want to be having to track that kind of state, really.

Comment: Good Catch!  To simplify the problem I took out the code NSManagedObject *managedObject = ((STLogSectionModel *)self.sectionModels[indexPath.section]).rowModels[indexPath.row];  So it looks like I'm managing another array.

Man, that worked beautifully!  Tomorrow I will build another UITableViewController using your method to display the remainder of the key/values of that object.  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh ok, great :) General lesson is never try to maintain additional flags and tags and whatnot about your model when you can just have the model represent all that implicitly, it saves a ton of code!

Comment: Hey!

Your Section Model is working beautifully each time that I have arrays.  I wanted to see if you have any recommendation for when I don't have arrays.  Most sections will have 1 cell.  Some sections will be out of order depending upon what options the user selects.  i.e. if the User wants to have drinks first and then movies, then drinks section will appear before the movies section. Here is my .m file.

Comment: https://github.com/kausainshaikh/PD/blob/master/pd.m    Your sectionModel has saved me tremendous amount of time writing if and else statements and I'm sure as you know, with more code comes more errors.  So thank you so very much!  I'm hoping you can make a similar suggestion here.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to take a look soon.

Comment: Take your time.  Thanks.  Let me know if you'd like me to start a new Question, so you can get credit.

Comment: Cool. May be a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com actually!

Comment: Here it is:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30059/ios-numberofrowsinsection-cellforrowatindexpath-refactor-to-avoid-if-and-els  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, whatsup!  I thought I'd check-in to see if you had a chance to look at the code and suggest an efficient method? or am I stuck with if-else- method?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1107173 I favorited it over on C.R. but haven't had a chance to read it in detail. Planning to get to it this weekend actually! Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to assign a tag for every new cell right?

Just define a static tag like this

```
#define CELL_TAG 100000
```

Now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row + CELL_TAG
```

The postfix expression which you have added will always increases the tag so remove that too.

PS. Where is the cell initialization? incase you need that

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```